# Updating ReactiveList from DataGrid changes in cell

Tags: c#, wpf, reactiveui

I'm trying to bind a `ReactiveList` to a `DataGrid` and I'd like to bind to the `ItemChanged` event or even the `Changed` event of the list so that I can update a `Total` variable that is the sum of the items in the list.

Here's my list declaration:

```
private ReactiveList<AllocationMatrix> _matrixItems;
public ReactiveList<AllocationMatrix> MatrixItems
{
  get => _matrixItems; set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _matrixItems, value);
}

_matrixItems = new ReactiveList<AllocationMatrix>()
{ ChangeTrackingEnabled = true };
```

Here's how I'm binding to the change event:

```
this.WhenAnyObservable(x => x._matrixItems.Changed)
.Subscribe(x =>
{
  Trace.WriteLine("Changed");
});
```

And finally, the datagrid for which I'm trying to get a change event thrown by editing a single cell (not adding or removing rows).

```
<DataGrid x:Name="MatrixGrid"
  ItemsSource="{Binding MatrixItems, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}"
...
```

For some reason the `Changed` and the `ItemChanged` events are not being triggered when editing a cell, but it seems to be thrown if I add or remove a row (which is not what I need).  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

you can try with `ObservableCollection<T>`

For example:

```
ObservableCollection<int> collection = new ObservableCollection<int>();
var observable = Observable.FromEventPattern<NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs>(collection,"CollectionChanged");

observable.Subscribe(a => { Console.WriteLine("Collection Changed !!!!! ");Debugger.Break(); });

collection.Add(1);
```

Let me know if that help you.

Comment: Is `ObservableCollection` a part of ReactiveUI?  I'd like a ReactiveUI specific answer if possible, since that's what I'm building in.

Comment: No, `ObservableCollection` isn't part of ReactiveUI, but honestly I have had bad experiences with ``ReactiveList`